# Getting HTTP request string from HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'd like to get the "string" version of the HTTP request that I am about to send with HttpRequestMessage.  Is there an easy way to do this, or do I need to generate something similar on my own?

```
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.ToString();
```

And get something like this:

```
 GET https://test.com/ HTTP/1.1
 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
 Content-Type: application/json
 Authorization: Basic Yasjkdhaksjdhakjdhak==
 Host: test.com
 Connection: Keep-Alive
 Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: did you found an answer?

Comment: @glm unfortunately not.  At least not one that isn't custom built.